# How do I avoid getting a object with nested values here?

Tags: powershell

```
$BloatedObject = invoke-RestMethod "https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCegWLyW4CYzph4dYW-gYy0g"
```

The above object contains many properties that I don't wish to continue working with from this point forward. So I thought. I would just take the two properties that I care for and store them in new object:

```
$SmallObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Title = $BloatedObject.Title
    Link = $BloatedObject.VideoID
}
```

But instead of getting something akin to the output of `$BloatedObject | Select-Object Title,VideoId`:

```
title                                                                                               videoId
-----                                                                                               -------
Fast Game World Prototyping | Thomas Tobin | EPC 2023                                               Duhdhc1JEwo
KineFX: Animating Environments and Props | Mihnea Stoica | EPC 2023                                 T8al2Uxsq70
Massive Worlds – Crafting World Partition Landscapes using Houdini | Erwin Heyms | EPC 2023         baM-3JWcPJE
PDG for Games | Simon Verstraete | EPC 2023                                                         hIBnwrNHsZo
Finding Patterns – The Math Behind HEXAGONA | Christos Stavridis | EPC 2023                         nbxhnCvexdA
...
```

I get a nested object:

```
Title
-----
{Fast Game World Prototyping | Thomas Tobin | EPC 2023, KineFX: Animating Environments and Props | Mihnea Stoica | EPC 2023, Massive Worlds – Crafting World Partition Landscapes using Houdini | Erwin Heyms | EPC 2023, PDG for Games | Simon Ver…
```

Well, why not just go with `$BloatedObject | Select-Object Title,VideoID` ?

Because in between the process of moving the properties `Title` and `VideoID` to the new  `$smallObject`, I also want to transform all the values of property `VideoID`:

```
$SmallObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Title = $BloatedObject.Title
    Link  = $BloatedObject.VideoID -replace "^", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="
}
```

So that `$SmallObject.Link` will look like:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Duhdhc1JEwo
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8al2Uxsq70
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=baM-3JWcPJE
...
```

I have been at this for hours and I am out of tricks. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you can just use a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.3), seem to be exactly what you're looking for:

```
$BloatedObject = Invoke-RestMethod "https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCegWLyW4CYzph4dYW-gYy0g"
$smallObjects = $BloatedObject | Select-Object title, @{ N = 'link'; E = { 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + $_.VideoId }}
```

Or reconstruct the objects yourself:

```
$smallObjects = $BloatedObject | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        title = $_.title
        link  = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + $_.VideoId
    }
}
```

Comment: More than finishing the function I was working on, I really wanted to grasp this object stuff. Your two examples were perfect. Thank you for that.